# Google charts showing wrong numbers on left side

Tags: php, mysql, charts, google-visualization

Databse query

```
$result = $polaczenie->query("SELECT data, SUM(uslugi.cena) FROM wizyty, uslugi WHERE wizyty.iduslugi = uslugi.iduslugi AND status = 'Zakończona' GROUP BY data") or die($polaczenie-> error);
```

Chart

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
          google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

          function drawChart() {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
              ['data', 'cena'],
              <?php
                if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                        echo "['".$row['data']."', ['".$row['SUM(uslugi.cena)']."']],";
                    }
                }
                ?>
            ]);

            var options = {
              title: 'Utarg',
              hAxis: {title: 'data',  titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'}},
              vAxis: {minValue: 0}
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
          }
        </script>
```

[image]

My problem is why there is no proper scale for 'cena' on the left of chart?
There are only random numbers. How i can fix that? 'cena' column in database is integer type if that helps.

Comment: What is the result of your query in phpmyadmin?

Comment: 2020-01-10->380 / 
2020-01-11->1540 / 
2020-01-13->160 / 
2020-01-15->65

Comment: You shouldn't be calling the google charts api at all untill you confirm that `mysqli_num_rows($result)>0` is true.  You should not manually craft a json string, in php simply pass your indexed array of indexed arrays to `json_encode()`.  Have a look at `mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM)`

Comment: What does the generated client-side source code look like?

Answer (score 0):

a couple things,

the second value in the data row should be a number, not a string.
and it should not be encapsulated inside brackets as an array.

```
echo "['".$row['data']."', ['".$row['SUM(uslugi.cena)']."']],";
```

remove the single quotes from the second value,
and remove the brackets...

```
echo "['".$row['data']."', ".$row['SUM(uslugi.cena)']."],";
```